# (Google Cloud Speech) Issue about Asynchronous Transcribe

Tags: php, google-cloud-speech

I have an issue about Google Cloud Speech with Asynchronous transcribe. According to this [LINK](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas) that

> Asynchronous can make requests up to 180 minutes.

I created the speech to text program by using Google Cloud Speech with PHP development. My idea is using FFMPEG to convert a file to .FLAC with 16 kHz of sample rate hertz and then running operation with Google Cloud Speech. All of the operations go smoothly when I upload the audio file with 1 or 3 minutes. Now I tried to upload the audio file more than 3 minutes (5 minutes and 60 minutes). The operations can't transcribe from speech to text and go to the exception of

> 'Job has not yet completed'

(Please see this [LINK](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize) for sample google PHP code) and then stuck at this message. My issue is

1. Shall I transcribe from speech to text with 60 minutes (or more but not exceed to 180 minutes) per audio
   file?
2. I don't clear about Request Limits of this API. According to [the
   quotas & limits page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas), it's mean that I can only request maximum to 100 seconds per single audio file. Did I think it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: You link Google's code, but where is your's that you have tried?

Comment: @SamSwift웃 I used that code for transcribing speech to text operation. The audio file uploaded to a bucket of Google Cloud Storage and then running this operation

Comment: It makes no odds - without seeing what you yourself have done, we cannot do a thing for you

Answer (score 1):

From document (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas), long audio files (180 minutes *), must use the uri field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage.
Example :
The name of the audio file to transcribe
$fileName = 'Your_directory/audio.raw';
Change to
$fileName = 'URL_To_Your_gs/audio.raw';